# Need help understanding how to implement memoization

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion, memoization

I'm trying to work through my first exercise in implementing memoization, and I can't wrap my head around how to do it for this problem:

I have a function that wraps input text to a specified line length, then prints the result.

```
def wrap(input, lineSpaces):
    if len(input) <= lineSpaces:
        return input
    temp = input.rfind(" ", 0, lineSpaces - 1)
    if temp == -1:
        return input
    else:
        return input[:temp+1]+'\n'+wrap(input[temp+1:], lineSpaces)

# I/O
list = []
M = int(raw_input())
for i in xrange(0, M):
    lineSpaces = int(raw_input())
    input = raw_input()
    list.append(wrap(input, lineSpaces))

for i in list:
    print i+"\n"
```

My current attempt at memoizing:

```
def wrap(input, lineSpaces):
    if len(input) <= lineSpaces:
        return input
    temp = input.rfind(" ", 0, lineSpaces - 1)
    if temp == -1:
        return input
    else:
        return input[:temp+1]+'\n'+wrap(input[temp+1:], lineSpaces)

# I/O
inputList = []
lineSpacesList = []
unmemoizedOutput = []
M = int(raw_input())
memo = {}

for i in xrange(0, M):
    lineSpacesList.append(int(raw_input()))
    inputList.append(raw_input())
    unmemoizedOutput.append(wrap(inputList[i], lineSpacesList[i]))

for i in unmemoizedOutput:
    if not i in memo:
        for j in xrange(0, M):
            memo[i] = i + wrap(inputList[j], lineSpacesList[j])
    print memo[i]+"\n"
```

I'm not getting the output I want. When I input:

```
3
20
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. A
30
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cu
36
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
```

I get:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor 
sit amet, 
consectetuer 
adipiscing elit. ALorem ipsum dolor sit amet,

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 
consectetuer adipiscing 
elit. Aenean commodo ligula 
eget dolor. Aenean massa. CuLorem ipsum dolor sit amet,

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
```

Which is obviously wrong. It looks like the only thing my "memoized" version is doing is appending the final output to every other output. So, I think my understanding of how to actually implement memoization for this function is completely off. Could someone please point me in the right direction?

Comment: Incidentally, this function isn't particularly suited for memoization. Memoization is particularly useful for [dynamic programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming), where you make the same recursive calls over and over. There, it can turn exponential-time algorithms linear-time. Here, the recursion doesn't get to take advantage of the memo, and I don't know if you're likely to try to word-wrap the same text repeatedly. (Maybe you are. I suppose it depends on the application.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Memoization is something you do when implementing a function, not when using it. When you produce an output, you record that the input of this call corresponds to the output you produced. When you get a call, you check whether you already have a stored output for the input you received, and you use the stored output if you do. It looks like this:

```
_memodict = {}
def memoized_function(input):
    try:
        return _memodict[input]
    except KeyError:
        # do what you would have normally done
        _memodict[input] = output
        return output
```

or like this:

```
import functools
def memoize(function):
    _memodict = {}

    # This decorator just makes the new function look a bit nicer
    @functools.wraps(function)
    def wrapped(*args):
        try:
            return _memodict[args]
        except KeyError:
            output = _memodict[args] = function(*args)
            return output
    return wrapped

@memoize
def function(input):
    # Exactly what you would have written normally
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, that makes a lot more sense. I think I have something now-- do you know any way to make sure the memoization function is actually working aside from confirming that I have the expected output, print statement debugging, etc.?

Comment: @user3681725: Make sure that recursive calls hit the memo too, by calling the memoized function with one of the inputs that would have occurred in an earlier recursive call and verifying that the function takes the quick path. If you write a memoization decorator, you can try it with the naive recursive Fibonacci implementation (the one that does `fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)`). Memoized, that implementation should be able to handle inputs like `fib(200)`. If the memoization isn't working, inputs like that won't ever finish.

Comment: Alright, good idea. It looks like it works pretty quickly on everything `fib(124)` and under, but anything over greater than that causes a `RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded`. Do you think that needs to be fixed for my original function?

Comment: @user3681725: I'm not sure where the extra stack frames are coming from. It could just be benign differences between your implementation and mine, or it could be a problem. I'm leaning towards "not a problem".